# Azure Data Warehouse "Failed to Pause Database" error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-synapse

I haven't been able to pause my Azure Data Warehouse either through the Azure Portal or Powershell for the last 2 hours.  It keeps timing out.

I really do not want to leave it on over the weekend.  Any ideas?

DESCRIPTION Failed to pause the database: MyDatabase.

ErrorCode: 0

Error Message: Data Warehouse operation timed out. Please try again.

STATUS Error

TIME Friday, May 27, 2016, 3:58:41 PM

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general server tech support.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to hear that you had an issue with your database. Can you file a ticket using the instructions listed here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-create-support-ticket/

We will investigate the issue and get back to you as quickly as possible.